# K-Means Clustering Paritioning

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, k-means

I am using matlab and i have this very very big .mat file named MeansOfK that contains almost 5,000,000 x N. My test data consists of Car and Non-car. My problem is that when i try to use k-means to the MeansofK. It always runs out of memory.

```
[idx, ctr] = kmeans(MeansOfK , k, 'Distance', 'sqEuclidean');
```

My Options are

1.i use the divide and conquer technique wherein i partition the car and non-car to smaller partitions and put it into k-means.

2.I separate the car and non-car classes and try to use k-means to both classes.

the final output would be the combined classes of car or non-car. from the k-means process.

so my question is?

Is what i will be doing feasible? 
Will it affect the output of my k-means if i partition the file rather than doing it as a whole?

Suggestions and answers are always appreciated :) 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried allocating the amount of memory used when you run the algorithm?

Comment: Yes, i have allocated my ram memory to max for matlab. Turned off my paging in my computer. But it is still out of memory. Buying is still not an option for me since i'm currently out of money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, you can leverage results of [Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) where you embed you dataset into lower dimension space and when doing the kmeans computation on smaller dataset. For instance if you data matrix is A you can do:

```
% N is the number of data points and s is the reduced dimension
S  =  randn (N, s)/s q r t (s) ;
C  =  A ∗ S ;

% now you can do you kmeans computation on C
[idx, ctr] = kmeans(MeansOfK , k, 'Distance', 'sqEuclidean');
```

Basically you can use `idx` and `ctr` results for original dataset which will give you (1+epsilon) approximation. Also you can reach better results based on work by [Dan Feldman](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1e76/727be351d6289311d9d1d65c494a683ace0f.pdf) which basically says that you can compute and SVD on your data and project on k/epsilon engine values to compute the kmeans value and get (1+epsilon) approximation.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on comment I'd like to suggest to leverage coresets approach, again based on the paper of Dan Feldman at el, [Turning Big Data Into Tiny Data](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1e76/727be351d6289311d9d1d65c494a683ace0f.pdf). The techniques provides with capability to reduce large volume of data into smaller with provable guarantee to provide (1+epsilon) approximation to the optimal kmeans solution. Moreover you can proceed with streaming coreset construction which will allow you to maintain `O(logn * epsilon)` approximation while streaming you data (section 10, figure 3), e.g. in your case partition into smaller chunks. When eventually you can run kmeans computation on the resulted coreset.

Also you probably might consider to take a look into my recent [publication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08990.pdf) to get more details on how to handle your case. Here you can find also a reference in my [github account](https://github.com/C0rWin/KMeanCoreset) if you'd like to use it.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, i didn't said in my question that the 5000000 x N had already been reduced. We used PCA as a dinension reduction for it.

Comment: You have dimension of 5000000 after reduction? I am afraid to ask what is the initial dimension was?

Comment: @ArtemBarger, I am trying to implement basic coreset calculation from the paper let say for 13k rows and 5 dimensions data, but having some difficulties wrapping my head on it even after looking through implementation on your github. Could you explain more with formula like you did above for Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your only real option if increasing memory is not possible is to partition the data into smaller sets. When i ran a big data project using collaborative filtering algorithms we used to deal with sets as large as 700 million + and whenever we maxed out the memory it meant we needed to partition the data into smaller sets and run the algorithms on them separately.